# Why ls | wc outputs 3 lines in dir with 3 one-line files?

Tags: ls, wc

```
$ ls
1.txt   2.txt   3.txt
$ ls | wc
       3       3      18
```

All three files has only 1 line, but ls|wc outputs '3'.

Comment: What were you expecting it to output? It sounds like you thought it would give you the number of lines in each file, is that right?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this. I don't think that the user is actually trying to count the number of lines from the `ls` command, but from the individual files.

Comment: Reluctantly VTO. Alexandr, you need to [edit] your question to explain more clearly what you were expecting.

Comment: Now I realise that I don't know what the question is. Please clarify. (3 × 1 is 3, so should not be unexpected).

Answer (score 5):

Try `ls | cat` to see how ls formats output differently when piped, compared to when sent to terminal.

Comment: Is this what the OP meant? It sounds like they were expecting a count of the lines in each file: "All three files has only 1 line, but ls|wc outputs '3'.".

Answer (score 3):

`ls`, when outputting to anything other than a terminal, behaves like `ls -1` (that's the digit `1`, not "ell") and outputs each name on a new line.

If you would want to count the number of line in the `ls` output as it would have appeared had it not been piped at all, use `ls -C`.  The `-C` option to `ls` forces multi-column output regardless of where that output is directed.

That is, use

```
ls -C | wc
```

or, to just get the line count,

```
ls -C | wc -l
```

---

On the other hand, if you wanted to count the number of lines in the three files, individually, you would have used

```
wc -l -- *
```

This would, if each file contained exactly one line, result in the output

```
   1 1.txt
   1 2.txt
   1 3.txt
   3 total
```

That is, each file contains one line, and the total number of lines in the three files is three.

The *difference* between `wc -l -- *` and `ls -C | wc -l` (or, `ls | wc` as you wrote), is from where `wc` gets its input.

With `ls -C | wc -l`, `wc` reads from *the output of `ls`* and would therefore count the number of lines that the `ls` command produced. Not the number of lines in any file.

With `wc -l -- *`, we tell `wc` to read *specific files*.  In this case, the files corresponding to the names that the wildcard ("filename globbing pattern") `*` expands to.

`wc -l -- *` is equivalent to `wc -l -- 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt` if those are the only files in the directory.

Note that if one the files in the current directory is called `-`, that wouldn't work properly as `wc` interprets a `-` argument as meaning *standard input*. One way to work around that would be to use `wc -l ./*` instead (`./-` is not special to `wc`), but that means that `./` prefix will also show in the output of `wc`.

Comment: Is this what the OP meant? It sounds like they were expecting a count of the lines in each file: "All three files has only 1 line, but ls|wc outputs '3'.".

Comment: @terdon Thanks! I might have overlooked that. I will make an addition about it.

Answer (score 1):

`ls` is giving you 3 columns which is different than single line, thus `wc` is counting new line after each column end. In other words, `ls` outputs formatted text, even though you don't see that. But `wc` does.

Comment: a single line of 3 columns wouldn't have 3 newlines

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. What i wanted to say is that ls is giving thre lines a s a result, formatted in three columns. wc counts actual new lines that poster doesn't see. Would that be better explanation?